# перезагрузка страницы после ajax скрипта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

аякс скрипт возвращает такую строку

```
echo '<div class="opu">Статус успешно изменен на Готово!</div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=lk-hot-cold-shop">';
```

как сделать чтобы он обновлял страницу без урла `url=lk-hot-cold-shop"`?

Comment: Странная строка во первых ,потому что присутствует строка `echo`. во вторых поясните что вы имеете в виду говоря `без урла url=lk-hot-cold-shop"`. вам нужно перейти по url `lk-hot-cold-shop` ?

Comment: я могу выполнять один ajax на нескольких страницах, в данный момент у меня аякс возвращает сообшение перенаправляет на страницу lk-hot-cold-shop, а надо чтобы перенаправлял на ту страницу , с которой был выполнен

Comment: А обязательно перезагружать страницу ? можно просто кусок с div  ом вставить в нужное место.Пример на jquery `var result = '<div class="opu">Статус успешно изменен на Готово!</div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=lk-hot-cold-shop">'; var message = $(result ).find('div'); $('body').prepend(message)`

Comment: да обязательно перезагрузка

Comment: Аякс происходит после срабатывания какого то ивента,onclick например  ? если да то просто после аякс прописать следующее `location.reload();`

Comment: Если перезагрузка обязательно, то вообще в чем смысл ajax?

Answer (score -1):

Ajax получает ответ от php обработчика, вот что обработчик послал то вы и получили в ответ на ваш запрос. Значит надо найти обработчик в php коде и поменять то, что он отдает.